# Innosetup installs unwanted tiles on Windows 8 Start Menu Tiles

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, inno-setup

I use InnoSetup to install my desktop application which consists of several exe's. Each exe ends up with its own tile in the tiles matrix. I really don't want all of the exe's to have a tile. Is there to specify which of the exe's gets a tile placed in the tiles matrix?

Comment: How many items did you define in [Icons] section? The tiles you see come from there.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15522972/588306) about grouping and adding custom icons

Answer (score 1):

Just find in an another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522972/creating-windows-8-start-screen-groups-and-tiles-not-only-for-exes-with-inno-s) the answer. You can control it with the `excludefromshowinnewinstall` flag.