# Creating Windows 8 Start screen groups and tiles (not only for exes) with Inno Setup

Tags: windows-8, installation, inno-setup, tile, startmenu

We are using Inno Setup to build installers for our [ActiveX grid control](http://www.10tec.com/). With the release of Win8, two new questions arose:

1. Is it possible to create our own new group of tiles on the Start screen (with a specified name) to place our shortcuts/tiles to it using InnoSetup?
2. Now, only the tiles for the exe's we install are created on the Start screen. Is it possible to add tiles for other file types - say, CHM help file or PDF documents - to this screen?

Comment: I don't have Windows 8 by hand, but to your first question; have you tried to force the group in the `Name` parameter, something like `Name: "{group}\Your Program"` ?

Comment: @TLama, Do you mean the Icons section? Yes, sure, we have it there but this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

The named grouping under "All appa" is created from the folder heirachy as with all versions of Windows since 95. This means you'd use code like this for all versions of Windows:

```
[Setup]
DefaultGroupName=Your app shortcuts

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Your app help"; ...
Name: "{group}\Your app registration"; ...
```

The only control you have over the main Windows 8 start screen is whether created shortcuts to executables get added automatically with the [`excludefromshowinnewinstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_iconssection.htm#excludefromshowinnewinstall) flag. You have no control over grouping as they're added to the end.